# How to let the git not tracking the large file history?

Tags: git

We somehow have an third-party library which need to check-in to our git project. And the library update frequently.

After some time, seams the git becomes huge, and it take long time when we clone it. So is there any way to delete the old version of the library, and just keep the `HEAD` version for each branch, so we can reduce size and the time to clone this git repository.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is a shallow clone

`git clone --depth 1`

This will checkout the repo with only a single item of history.

If you want to specify the branch to use (instead of the default "master" branch) use this syntax (requires Git 1.9+):

```
git clone -b <remoteBranch> --single-branch --depth 1 ssh://username@servername.net:serverport/PathToProject <FolderName>
```

Comment: So is it possible to reduce the server side disk space size?

Comment: No it won't reduce the size on the server but it will mean checking it out initially is faster - this could be used in jenkins and then you can work from this shallow clone.

Comment: You could always just remove the `.git` folder after it has been cloned to free up some additional space if you plan to `git clone --depth 1` each time a deploy occurs.